# How to get the index of label mouse clicked in JLabel [ ] [ ]?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I've got a two dimension array of `JLabel` components and I want to get the place where  the mouse clicked in the label like this.

```
Jlabel [x] [y] // I want this x & y
```

How should I do that?

I've tried this but I get nothing!

```
new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        int a=e.getX();
        int b=e.getY();
        MainBoard.ML.label=MainBoard.disk1[a][b];
        Color c=MainBoard.ML.label.getForeground();
        if(color==1)
            MainBoard.ML.label.setForeground(Color.black);
        else
            MainBoard.ML.label.setForeground(Color.white);
        new Play(a,b,color);
        new Player2(r);
        MainBoard.disk1[a][b].addMouseListener(new ML1(a,b));
    }
};
```

I want to get the x & y index of the label array.

Comment: You assign the MouseListener inside of the mousePressed event? Is that really what you want? You should assign a MouseListener to each JLabel when you create them.

Comment: I want to get  the place where mouse clicked and pass that to ML for doing an action, if you have any idea for doing it I'll appreciate that

Comment: If a mouse listener is added to the labels themselves, `e.getSource()` will obtain the label that was clicked. That's the only help I can (am willing to try to) provide based on the current info. For more or better advice: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: How should I use e.getSource() for this?

Comment: *"How should I use.."* Tip: Add @f1sh (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. As an aside, f1sh made a good point that you should address - the detection of the event is no place to be **adding** a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested and uncompiled code to locate *x* and *y* you are seeking is below.
Note that method `getX()` of class `MouseEvent` gets the location of the mouse pointer on the computer screen and not the *x* from your array. Similarly for method `getY()`. That's why you get nothing.

In the below code I add the same `MouseListener` to all the `JLabel`s.

The `MouseEvent` contains the `JLabel` that the mouse was clicked on and method `getSource()` of class `MouseEvent` returns it. Then you need to iterate through your array of `JLabel`s and see which one matches the `MouseEvent` source.

```
int rows = // number of rows in 2D array
int cols = // number of cols in 2D array
final JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[rows][cols]
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        Object src = me.getSource();
        int x = -1;
        int y = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < labels[i].length; j++) {
                if (src == labels[i][j]) {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (x >= 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (x > 0) {
            System.out.printf("JLabel[%d][%d] was clicked.%n", x, y);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Could not find clicked label.");
        }
    }
}
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        labels[row][col] = new JLabel(row + "," + col);
        labels[row][col].addMouseListener(ml);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your cooperating ,I just compile and test your code but I did'n get  anything again Do you mind if I send you my code to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @edie.lp the code I posted is not a complete program, it's only to help you get started.

Comment: Thank you for your help